# How to retrieve from Browser the bookmarks folders hierarchy

Tags: android, browser, cursor, directory, bookmarks

I'm using the following query for retrieving the bookmarks of the default browser in Android:

```
    public static void loadBookmarks(Context context){ 

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            Browser.BookmarkColumns._ID,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.FAVICON,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE,
    };

    String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + "=1"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark

    Cursor mCur = context.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            projection, sel, null, bookmarksSortBy);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    int titleIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
    int urlIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);
    int i = 1;
    while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
        StringBuffer bookmark = new StringBuffer("Bookmark #").append(i).append("\n Bookmark Title=");
        bookmark.append(mCur.getString(titleIdx));
        bookmark.append("\n bookmark URL=" + mCur.getString(urlIdx));
        mCur.moveToNext();
        LogWrapper.d(bookmark.toString());
        i++;
    }            

}
```

I would like to know how I can expand this above code to retrieve also the Bookmarks hierarchy of folders, i.e. how does the query look and the extraction from the answer looks.
A code example will be appreciated. 
Thanks